# How to query from an Influx database with an absent field?

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

I have a measurement gathered by telegraf. It has following structure:

name: smart_device

```
fieldKey    fieldType
--------    ---------
exit_status integer
health_ok   boolean
read_error_rate integer
seek_error_rate integer
temp_c      integer
udma_crc_errors integer
```

When I query this database I can do this:

```
> select  * from smart_device where  "health_ok" = true limit 1
name: smart_device
time            capacity    device  enabled exit_status health_ok   host    model           read_error_rate seek_error_rate serial_no   temp_c  udma_crc_errors wwn
----            --------    ------  ------- ----------- ---------   ----    -----           --------------- --------------- ---------   ------  --------------- ---
15337409500 2000398934016   sda Enabled     0           true        osd21   Hitachi HDS722020ALA330    0        0       JK11A4B8JR2EGW  38  0       5000cca222e6384f
```

and this:

```
> select  * from smart_device limit 1
name: smart_device
time            capacity    device  enabled exit_status health_ok   host    model   read_error_rate seek_error_rate serial_no   temp_c  udma_crc_errors wwn
----            --------    ------  ------- ----------- ---------   ----    -----   --------------- --------------- ---------   ------  --------------- ---
1533046990                   sda            0                      osd21
```

But when I try to filter out records with empty `health_ok`, I get empty output:

```
> select  * from smart_device where "health_ok"!= true 
>
```

How can I select measurements with empty (no? null?) `health_ok`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to do this using InfluxQL. InfluxDB is a form of document oriented database; it means rows of a measurement can have different schema. Therefore, there is no a concept of null for a field of a row; actually this row dose not have the field. for example suppose there are 4 rows in the measurement *cost*

```
> select * from cost
name: cost
time                isok type value
----                ---- ---- -----
1533970927859614000 true 1    100
1533970938243629700 true 2    101
1533970949371761100      3    103
1533970961571703900      2    104
```

As you can see, there are two rows with `isok=true` and two rows which have no field named `isok`; so there is only one way to select the time of rows which have the `isok` field with this query:

```
> select isok from cost
name: cost
time                isok
----                ----
1533970927859614000 true
1533970938243629700 true
```

Since InfluxQL currently dose not support subquery in where clause, therefor there is no way to query for rows with no `isok` field (If InfluxDB supports this type of query, you can query like this `SELECT * FROM cost WHERE time NOT IN (SELECT isok FROM cost)`)

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the answer for the original question, but I found a special trick for Kapacitor.

If this query has been executed by kapacitor, it (kapacitor) has a special node `default` which allows to add missing fields/tags with some value.

For the `health_ok` query it will look like this (tickscript):

```
var data = stream
    |from()
      .measurement('smart_device')
        |default()   
           .field('health_ok', FALSE)
```

This allows to assume that if health_ok is missed, it is `FALSE`.