# How to indicate that a there has been no data from query for x amount of time in Grafana?

Tags: database, grafana, influxdb

I have time series data of temperatures from x10 different sensors, stored in an InfluxDB (v1.8) database, and am displaying the “current” value using a Bar Gauge.

The sensors should get a new value roughly every hour, but I would like some way to show if the sensor has failed (e.g. hasn’t had any data for let’s say 1 day). The problem is that data is always being displayed, no matter how old it is (as expected, because I am selecting [`LAST`](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/query-data/influxql/functions/selectors/#last)):

[image]

I have tried to use a `WHERE time>now() - “some time”` clause in InfluxDB, but now the relevant values have been removed entirely:

[image]

What would be a good way to fix this? (ideally whilst still taking advantage of the `GROUP_BY` feature that I’m using, which is nice)

Comment: Are you asking for SQL advice or for UI advice (or both)?  It isn't clear to me.

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell. I don't mind if the filtering is done on the database side or the UI side. But ultimately I am only looking to indicate in the UI display that the values are missing. By the way, its not SQL, its InfluxDB (v 1.8).

Comment: As you don't seem to have case expression capability: Let's assume the source data has a column called **measured_at** which is a timestamp. Amend your current query to return both the last(temperature) **and the last(measured_at)** in your application code test if that lasT(measured_at) value is greater than 1 hour ago, and if that is true place a warning on screen.

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell This is what I want help with - the Grafana side of things. (I also don't want to duplicate all the timestamps into a new column, increasing data usage. InfluxDB automatically timestamps data).

Comment: create a [deadman check](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/monitor-alert/checks/create/) in influxdb then for [grafana this blog may help](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/08/12/streaming-real-time-sensor-data-to-grafana-using-mqtt-and-grafana-live/) using that check. I don't use either product, but this appears relevant to your needs.

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell Unfortunately those links won't work for me. The Grafana blog is about streaming live data onto the graphs - I am just trying to have a flag which tells me a value has been absent for some time. The InfluxDB deadman check you mentioned is for InfluxDB Cloud (not v.18 open source as I am using).

Answer (score 0):

try the `fill`  in your time grouping, which allows you to specify how to handle missing data in your query results. e.g.  `fill(previous)` to report the value from the previous time interval for time intervals with no data or  use `fill(null)` to fill the missing values with null or None, and then use `InfluxDB's` built-in `fill` function to perform any additional queries and actions on the data².

```sql
SELECT LAST(temperature) FROM sensors
WHERE time > now() - 7d
GROUP BY time(1h), sensor_id
FILL(previous)
```

This query will return the last temperature value for each sensor in each hour for the past 7 days, & fill any gaps with the previous value. other options such as `linear`, `none`, or a specific value to fill the missing data

---

References:

1. [InfluxDB: How to deal with missing data? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75360882/influxdb-how-to-deal-with-missing-data).
2. [Timeseries (InfluxDB): How to deal with missing data? - Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/118322/timeseries-influxdb-how-to-deal-with-missing-data).
3. [InfluxDB: query aggregations but deal with missing data - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640398/influxdb-query-aggregations-but-deal-with-missing-data).
4. [influxdb - How to query from an Influx database with an absent field - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788320/how-to-query-from-an-influx-database-with-an-absent-field).
5. [InfluxDB Documentation: Query Data Fill](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/fill/).
6. [InfluxDB Documentation: Query Language Data Exploration](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/).

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I believe this approach doesn't work. I agree that I can select further back in time to ensure that the last value of the dead sensor appears (e.g. you did this with "WHERE time>now()-7d"). However, if I use fill(null) then the last value of the "good, working" sensors is null (which is not what I want - I want it to show the most recent value). Instead I can use fill(previous), which correctly gives values for working sensors, but gives the last value of the broken sensor as it's previous working value (in which case I can't tell that it's broken anymore).